# How to check a tar.xz file to see if it's not corrupted

Tags: tar, xz

I have compressed some file with this command:

```
XZ_OPT=-e9 tar cJf compressed_directory.tar.xz /path/to/directory
```

Is there any way I could check these `tar.xz` files to see if they're not corrupted? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

I searched for my question and there are several answers but all of them are for `tar.gz`, I'm looking for a way to check `tar.xz`.

Comment: It's unclear whether you want to check whether the files in the `tar` archive are ok, or whether you just want to make sure that the compression is correct.  Answers for `tar.gz` files are valid for `tar.xz` files seeing as `gzip` and `xz` both has `-t` with the same semantics and otherwise also work the same.

Comment: Try sudo tar -tvf name.tar.xz

Comment: @Sysadmin Why do you suggest using `sudo` in this particular case?

Comment: @Kusalananda It doesn't matter to me, I want to make sure that if I delete that directory, I have a backup in that `tar.xz` file, so doesn't matter which one is corrupted

Answer (score 1):

`xz -t *xz` will test it for you however it cannot test the integrity of the TAR archive itself because TAR by default doesn't do checksumming.

To be extra safe in this case I use this one liner:

```
find directory -depth | cpio -o -H crc | xz -9e directory.cpio.xz
```

In this case you can always check whether the source archive have all the files intact.

Comment: Thanks, can you add a little explanation about what does `cpio` and other commands and switches do?